# Does Linq to Sql close connections automatically?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Does Linq to Sql Close connections automatically? or I should use `using`?

```
var db = new DataContext();
// Codes
```

or

```
using (var db = new DataContext())
{
    // Codes
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using the `using` statement then the connection will be managed automatically.The `DataContext` class implements the `IDisposable` interface, so what you need to is to call Dispose on the `DataContext` implementation whenever you are finished with it.

From the [C# In Depth](http://csharpindepth.com/ViewNote.aspx?NoteID=89)

> There are a few reasons we implemented IDisposable:
>
> - If application logic needs to hold onto an entity beyond when the    DataContext is expected to be used or valid you can enforce that
>     contract by calling Dispose. Deferred loaders in that entity will
>     still be referencing the DataContext and will try to use it if any
>     code attempts to navigate the deferred properties. These attempts
>     will fail. Dispose also forces the DataContext to dump its cache of
>     materialized entities so that a single cached entity will not
>     accidentally keep alive all entities materialized through that
>     DataContext, which would otherwise cause what appears to be a memory
>     leak.
> - The logic that automatically closes the DataContext connection can be    tricked into leaving the connection open. The DataContext relies
>     on    the application code enumerating all results of a query since
>     getting    to the end of a resultset triggers the connection to close.
>     If the    application uses IEnumerable's MoveNext method instead of a
>     foreach    statement in C# or VB, you can exit the enumeration
>     prematurely. If    your application experiences problems with
>     connections not closing    and you suspect the automatic closing
>     behavior is not working you can    use the Dispose pattern as a work
>     around.

Comment: `.Dispose()` close connection?

Comment: @Mohamadshiralizadeh:- You can refer http://csharpindepth.com/ViewNote.aspx?NoteID=89

Comment: `Close()` actually calls `Dispose()`, but the `using` statement automatically calls dispose on the resource, so just use `using` and don't be afraid of closing or disposing.

Comment: @pid:- Yes thats correct when we are using the using statement then we dont have to worry about the closing the connection(*which I have updated in my answer also*)

Comment: @Mohamadshiralizadeh:- When we are using the using statment then the dispose method is called automatically. The point is when we are using the DataContext then it should always be "destroyed" or Disposed, so optimally you should use the Context object inside an using statement:

Answer (score 1):

The `using` version is the best you can do. The underlying connection is not closed and this is a good thing. Connections are kept in a pool so that they may be recycled.

Don't confuse your code *closing* a connection with the actual underlying physical connection.

You must close the connection and the best way to handle this (best practice) is the `using` statement.

Comment: you mean first version doesn't close connection?

Comment: No, the first version does not close the connection until the application context is disposed of (that is, when the application terminates). The using statement is a recommended best practice, there really is no argument against it.

Comment: is .net source i see this in QqlProvider that Linq uses `...    }
    finally
    {
        this.conManager.ReleaseConnection(this);
    }
    return result;
}` What is it? it exactly says that linq to sql close connections after any execute..